# Run SonarCloud in Visual Studio Code on entire project structure

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, sonarlint

I'm using SonarCloud to maintain/improve the code quality of our Angular5 application. I installed the SonarCloud plugin in VSC and it shows its warnings/problems as soon as I open a TypeScript file, if any found. So far, so good.

Unfortunately, SonarCloud analysis is triggered at file level and not on project level. I want to run it on the entire project and see all the warnings/problems in a complete list. Opening all files on a single basis in order to see the warnings seems impractical to me.

When I open the Command Palette in VSC, I would have expected a command like "Run analysis" but there is none. How can I trigger the analysis for the complete project?